# Gravity Forms save progress and email link to continue

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a requirement for a project that allows users to fill in a form partially and then save the progress until they have all the information they require to process the form.

The form is on one page only and our user do NOT register and they must not have to register even for saving progression.

What I need is a way to save a form with all the data a user has inputted and then email the user a URL (the email is captured in the form) which will allow them to continue the form at a later date.

I have very little experience with gravity forms so I am unsure if this is something I am able to do out of the box or if there is a plugin that will assist me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I guess the fastest way to do that, is to use your PHP skills

Answer (score 2):

I believe 'Save & Continue' functionality is in the next Gravity Forms version core (1.9).  I think beta is due to be released shortly...

According to my understanding of it, this should cover most of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

While I have no experience with it, here is a link to an add-on that claims to save form status:

https://github.com/soulseekah/Gravity-Forms-Saved-Forms-Addon

and here's another one:

http://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-data-persistence-add-on/

in fact, here's a link to the google search I did. There seems to be several solutions to save the progress of a filled out Gravity Form.

https://www.google.com/search?q=gravity%20form%20save%20progress

Comment: All of those require user registration, which the original poster specifically mentioned he does not want.

Comment: As Naomi said they all need a user to register - I already had a google about and found these.